# Animation doesn't run

Tags: cocos2d-x

In cocos2d-x, the following animation code displays the sprite but does not run the animation. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
// create a CCAnimation node
CCAnimation * anim = CCAnimation::animation();

// add the images to the loop (one image per frame)
anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("Hero/1.png");
anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("Hero/2.png");
anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("Hero/3.png");

// create an action
CCAnimate * animation   = CCAnimate::actionWithAnimation( anim );
animation->setDuration(0.5);
CCAction * repeat       = CCRepeatForever::actionWithAction(animation);

// create a sprite to run the action
CCSprite * test = CCSprite::create("Hero/1.png");
test->setPosition( ccp( 150, 150 ) );
test->runAction( repeat );
this->addChild( test );
```

Comment: Ok, so adding `anim->setDelayPerUnit(1);` seems to solve the problem. Can anyone explain why and what the difference is between DelayPerUnit and Duration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a delay on the frames of the animation, CCAnimate will automatically figure out the duration so you don't need the `animation->setDuration()`

```
// create a CCAnimation node
CCAnimation * anim = CCAnimation::animation();

// add the images to the loop (one image per frame)
anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("Hero/1.png");
anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("Hero/2.png");
anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("Hero/3.png");
anim->setDelay(.5 / 3.0);
```

Also, I would start the animation after adding it as a child.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this is help ful for you

```
[anim  addFrameWithFilename:Hero/1.png];
id rep_frame;
id frameactions=[CCAnimate actionWithDuration:1.0 animation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:YES];    
rep_frame=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:frameactions];
[self runAction:rep_frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
CCAnimation * anim = CCAnimation::animation();
for (int i = 1; i <= 3 ; i++)
 // add the images to the loop (one image per frame)
anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName((CCString::createWithFormat("Hero/%d.png",i)->getCString()));
anim->setDelayPerUnit( 0.5f / 3.0f);
CCAnimate *action = CCAnimate::create(anim);

// create a sprite to run the action
CCSprite * test = CCSprite::create("Hero/1.png");
test->setPosition( ccp( 150, 150 ) );
test->runAction(CCRepeatForever::create(action)); // run action on sprite object
this->addChild( test );
```